# Rspec failing test where 'Diff:', looks identical

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

**Aim**

My program uses an algorithm to make a board, line-by-line in an array of arrays.

The final array looks like this (a standard 3x3 board with a border):

`[['-----'],['|...|'],['|...|'],['|...|'],['-----']]`

**Problem**

The failing test is as follows:

Note: `view_board` puts @board

`expect { board.view_board }.to output(['-----','|...|','|...|','|...|','-----']).to_stdout`

Outputting:

```
 `Failure/Error: expect { board.view_board }.to output(['-----','|...|','|...|','|...|','-----']).to_stdout
   expected block to output ["-----", "|...|", "|...|", "|...|", "-----"] to stdout, but output "-----\n|...|\n|...|\n|...|\n-----\n"
   Diff:`
```

**What'd different?**

I'm not sure if there's a space somewhere I've missed, if I change the final array to `"-----\n"`, then I get:

`Diff:
       @@ -2,5 +2,5 @@
        |...|
        |...|
        |...|
       ------\n
       +-----`

Edit:

**Board-Generating Code**

```
class Board
BOARD_ROW = '-'
BOARD_COLUMM = '|'
BEGINNING_AND_END_LENGTH = 2

def initialize(board_size = 3)
    @board = []
    @board_top_and_bottom = []
    @board_middle = []
    @board_size = board_size
end

def go
    set_board
end

def set_board
    set_board_top_and_bottom
    set_board_middle
    assemble_board
    view_board
end

def set_board_top_and_bottom
    (@board_size + BEGINNING_AND_END_LENGTH).times do 
        @board_top_and_bottom.push(BOARD_ROW)    
    end
    @board_top_and_bottom = [@board_top_and_bottom.join]
end

def set_board_middle
    add_board_edge
    add_board_spaces
    add_board_edge
    @board_middle = [@board_middle.join]
end

def add_board_spaces
    @board_size.times do 
        @board_middle.push('.')    
    end
end

def add_board_edge
    @board_middle << BOARD_COLUMM
end

def assemble_board
    @board << @board_top_and_bottom
    @board_size.times do
        @board << @board_middle
    end
    @board << @board_top_and_bottom
end

def view_board
    puts @board
end
end
```

Comment: Please show how the code looks like that builds and outputs the array.

Comment: Okay, I've done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs of [`puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-puts):

> `puts(obj, ...) → nil`
>   Writes the given object(s) to *ios*. Writes a newline after any that do not already end with a newline sequence. [...]

That means when your call `puts ['foo', 'bar']` then Ruby will actually output `"foo\nbar"`

To make your spec pass change the expectation to:

```
expect { board.view_board }.to output("-----\n|...|\n|...|\n|...|\n-----\n").to_stdout
```

Comment: RSpec's `output` matcher should probably print a warning when being called with a non-string (or regexp) argument.

Comment: @spickermann Apologies, pressed enter too soon. There's an extra \n at the end, I was just investigating.